# Elisp: how to implement better detailed printing?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I like to see all the possible information when I eval, so I've set

```lisp
(setq eval-expression-print-length nil)
(setq eval-expression-print-level nil)
```

This however creates serious slowdown when working with large data, for instance
with manipulating CEDET data.

So I'm thinking that a lazy-print system could work for me: print as much data as possible
up to the set limit (say 100000 characters) and abbreviate the rest.

So instead of current behavior with `print-level`:

```lisp
(foo (bar1 ... baz1)
     (bar2 ... baz2)
     (bar3 ... baz3))
```

I could have:

```lisp
(foo (bar1 __tmp1__ baz1)
     (bar2 __tmp2__ baz2)
     (bar3 __tmp3__ baz3))
```

where `__tmp1__` holds the value which `...` hide and can be expanded in `*scratch*` with some shortcut.
I could even add a `font-lock` rule to fontify `__tmp[0-9]+__` as `...`.

I'd like some pointers in implementing the described system (such as efficient generation,
storage and garbage collection of the abbreviation variables), or maybe
you could point me to a better system that solves the problem that I described.

Comment: The abbreviated output is often interactive, such that you can type `RET` to see the hidden content.

Comment: Wow, thanks. I didn't realize that. There's still an issue that eval-print-level and length aren't respected when I type `RET`, but maybe I can work around that.